# as3 hit test array multiple returns from boolean

Tags: actionscript-3, boolean

I want to check if my character is hitting any of the items in an array (true) and if he isn't (false).  right now the boolean is in a for loop so it returns one "true" and multiple "false" statements each time the program updates.  I just want one return, true if the character is hitting a movie clip in the array, and false if he isn't.  Here's the code:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<steps.length; i++){
            if(steps[i].hitTestPoint(hero.x,hero.y+hHeight/2, true)){
                onSteps = true;
            }else{
                onSteps = false;
            }   
}
```

Comment: You want to exit the loop returning true on the first true you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a function that goes through the steps array and then returns true as soon as one hits. If none have hit, it defaults to returning "false".

```
function checkForHits():Boolean {
    for(var i:int = 0; i<steps.length; i++){
        if(steps[i].hitTestPoint(hero.x,hero.y+hHeight/2, true)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @vince no problem : ) you can click the "accept" check-mark next to my answer if your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary078.html

and see also "return".

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` object already has a method

```
some(callback:Function, thisObject:* = null):Boolean
```

which returns `true` in the case that **any** element of the `Array` satisfies the callback function, and `false` in the case that **no** element of the `Array` satisfies the callback function.

Here's the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#some()

Your code would be something like:

```
onSteps = steps.some(function (item:*, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
            {
               return item.hitTestPoint(hero.x,hero.y+hHeight/2, true);
            });
```